# Problem with Google crawler and cached results

Tags: seo, google-search-console, wordpress, google-search, googlebot

I have a client that has 3 domain names. For the sake of this argument I will call them `www.website1.com`, `www.website2.com` and `www.website3.com`.

He used to have a website package with VistaPrint and `www.website1.com` was his main business website and website2 and website3 used to redirect to the main website.

However recently I created a new WordPress website for him and now his main domain name is `www.website3.com` and website1 and website2 simply redirect to the main website.

But when I go on Google and search for the domain name (any of the three) it does not show me the description of the website and it says: *A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more.*

I used to have a *robots.txt* file but have deleted it since the migration to the client's host however Google seems to have indexed it in the meanwhile. I got in touch with the hosting company and they said that it is a virtual file and that it doesn't physically exist - and that the issue with the description in Google is happening because it has indexed the website while the *robots.txt* was there.

I want all references to website1 and website2 to vanish from Google and I only want it to index `www.website3.com`, which is the main business website - with the correct description of the site

What are my options? I logged into Google Webmaster Tools and it still says that the file is there.

I hope you understand what I want to achieve but feel free to ask for clarification

Any advice will be greatly appreciated as I want to solve this issue ASAP before it starts damaging the client's online presence and reputation

Comment: just checked webmaster tools and this is what it says: `Googlebot is blocked from http://www.mydomain.com/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than delete your robots.txt file, you should upload one that explicitly allows all crawling.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

When you delete a robots.txt file, Google often uses the old one for some time period (maybe even weeks) to make sure that you didn't delete it by accident.

Comment: you are not going to believe it! I seem to have left an option ticked that says something like "Discourage crawlers to index this site" - so naturally I unticked it and what Wordpress did was modify the content of my htaccess file and the website was all of a sudden not available :error 500. Never thought Wordpress actually modifies the htaccess file

Comment: we learn something new everyday - I now know that messing with that WP option will update my htaccess file!!